# Creating FormGroup[] in angular2

Tags: angular

Hi i have created FormGroup which contains FormControls. I bound it to template which is working fine. Now i want to give functionality to user to create another same form meams FormGroup[] a button click. FormGroup[] size will keep increasing on each button click. And multiple form will start showing likewise. Each FormGroup should represent a form.

Comment: Can you provide some code that you have work with?

Answer (score 0):

It got resolved by creating normal FormGroup array.
And inserting Formcontrols inside it. Everytime add button wqs clicked. Just one trick. formControlName should be field name. But validation etc on the template should be done like FormGroup.controls.fieldname.errors.errorname.

Here direct access to fieldname would not work.